# how to only keep certain characters in a string

Tags: python

I'm just a beginner so this might be a stupid question but, I'm trying to remove every character from a string except the ones in a list

for example:
you have a string H][e,l}l.o1;4.I want only letters and numbers in the output.
It should look like this:
Hello14

Does anyone have any idea what needs to come behind the str1 = or any other methods?
This is what I tried so far:

```
def stringCleaner(s): 
    # initialize an empty string
    str1 = " " 
    chars = set('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    for x in range(len(s)):
        if any((c in chars) for c in s):
            str1= 
    return str1
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to simply iterate over your input string and create a list of allowed characters and `join()` the list into a string again at the end.

```py
def stringCleaner(s): 
    # initialize an empty list
    str1 = [] 
    chars = set('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    for c in s:
        if c in chars:
            str1.append(c) 
    return ''.join(str1)
```

And then you should be able to see that its only a few short steps to get even better code such as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69416321) that @user1740577 has posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can for any char in `s` check in `chars list` and `.join()` all of them if exist in `chars list`.

Try this:

```
def stringCleaner(s): 
    chars = set('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c in chars)

stringCleaner('H][e,l}l.o1;4.I')
# 'Hello14I'
```